# Get the heap dump when Tomcat runs OutOfMemory

Tags: java, tomcat, out-of-memory

I want to get the hprof file(dump) to analyze the OOME.

The application is deployed in tomcat, it is running as a windows service. I used this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554341/set-a-jvm-to-dump-heap-when-outofmemoryerror-is-thrown) to change my `catalina.bat` file and also tried by placing a `setenv.bat` file.
And then I manually generated out of memory in the application.

I can see the application going out of memory, but the dump is never created, am I missing something here ?

However in my local development environment when I used the `jvisualvm` to create the dump, the dump was successfully created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many things and in the end I found out that when the tomcat service is started as a service from the `tomcat.exe` setting the environment variables at `catalina.bat` will have no effect, for this tomcat has provided `tomcat7w.exe` this is present in the `/bin` directory.

But while configuring your tomcat as a windows service you have changed the name of that service to say `fooBar` then you need to rename `tomcat7w.exe` to `fooBarw.exe` and then you can configure different variables in the console window.