# java process OOMKilled beside container support

Tags: java, kubernetes, oom

I'm using Azul Java 17.0.10 which has default container support for cgroupsv2 and correctly inferences the Pods memory limit which is set to 1 GiB.

We directly run the java process as PID1 inside the container, but still under heavy load wese OOMKill for this container.

My mind model was that the JVM will not use any more memory then the cgroups memory limit.

But this doesn't seem to be true. How to find out what is causing the memory usage? Is there a way to get a stack trace of the offending memory request?

Comment: Obligatory: [Out-of-fuel killer](https://lwn.net/Articles/104185/).  If you want reliable performance from Linux, you have to disable the OOM killer and provide your systems with enough memory and swap space so they never run out of virtual memory.  Because Linux's memory overcommit means the kernel flat out **lies** to processes about access to memory.  "You want 4 GB of RAM? Here it is. ... Oh, I see you actually used the memory I said you could?  Guess what - **I LIED**.  You're killed!!!"

Comment: You could use [jattach](https://github.com/jattach/jattach) to grab a heap dump of the application during heavy load, then check the dump to find what is using memory and why.

Also, if the node where the application is running goes under heavy memory load, it might decide to kill Pods, especially if not running with Guaranteed QoS, check the [out of memory behavior](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/node-pressure-eviction/#node-out-of-memory-behavior)

Comment: you can use [HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23798578/175554) that will have dump file in case of out of memory then you can collect them analyze